# How use Fn::Include and Fn::Sub together?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

Consider this code:

```
MyStateMachine:
    Type: "AWS::StepFunctions::StateMachine"
    Properties:
        StateMachineName: MyStateMachine
        DefinitionString:
            Fn::Sub:
                - Fn::Transform:
                     Name: 'AWS::Include'
                     Parameters:
                         Location: s3://my-bucket/my.json
                - { Param1: MyLambda1.Arn, Param2: MyLambda2.Arn }
```

I got an error:

> Template error: One or more Fn::Sub intrinsic functions don't specify expected arguments.
>       Specify a string as first argument, and an optional second argument to specify a mapping
>       of values to replace in the string

It is required that first argument must be a string, but what if state machine has place holder for arn? How to replace them? Any workarounds?

Comment: Could you show us the content of  `s3://my-bucket/my.json`?

Answer (score 2):

`Fn::Sub` doesn't support `Fn::Transform` as part of the input. As stated in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html#w2ab1c21c24c59c13):

> For the String parameter, you cannot use any functions. You must
>   specify a string value.

One solution would be to include the state machine definition in the CloudFormation template directly, without resorting to `Fn::Transform` and `Fn::Include`, which would allow you to use `Fn::Sub` to replace the placeholders.

Depending on your reasoning behind putting the state machine definition in S3 that might even make sense from an architectural point of view, as you wouldn't need a separate S3 bucket for storing the state machine definition anymore and the definition would be tightly coupled to the CloudFormation stack which (presumably) creates the AWS Lambda functions which are used in the state machine anyway.

I'm afraid that's the only solution possible so far, because `Fn::Sub` is fairly limited in this regard. Even if you'd have the state machine definition available as string which can be referenced (e.g. as parameter) in your template you could only replace the reference with the state machine definition string, but not anything inside that string.